# Dynamic and lazy ListView

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` in my Fragment. The content of `ListView` is downloaded from webserver. Obviously, I don't download everything at once- I am going to download, for example, 30 items. And, `onScroll` I am going to download the `n-th` page.

1. How to solve it?

I see two solutions:

A. I've started a background thread and on scroll it downloads the next page and pass to UI thread. It seems to be good solution because I have one  thread to download elements.

B. I run AsyncTask onScroll. It seems to be worse solution- every scroll = creating a new thread   ( it is relatively expensive).

What do you think? What is the best solution in Android?

Comment: You seem to have settled for solution A. But I think it might be inefficient if you have to download a single page on each scroll. How about downloading and caching?

Comment: I usually use the solution A. You can check the other app, when you scroll down to end of the list, it will get the new list of next page.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches you described are fine. `AsyncTask` is good because it have limited execution - you don't have to manage his state much. So it's ok to create and start it. But in case of `Thread` you have to keep it live, manage delivery of request and somehow pass information back to the UI thread. So the simplier would be just create custom `AsyncTask`. Your solution shouldn't create more then one load at a time - if it does introduce some kind of limit.

Also you could search other solutions for `Infinite Scrolling` for android. [Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) is good resource to read.